# Docker image doesn't pull specific JAR from repository

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, gradle

When I build my project, I have created two jars using Gradle jar task,

```
jar {
enabled = true
classifier = 'boot'
}
```

So, I have two jars created in my repository.

I need to include my project as library for internal use(with `xxxxx-version-boot.jar`) and as microservice(with `xxxxx-version.jar`) for others to consume.

When I pull docker image created and start it, `xxxxx-version-boot.jar` is picked by docker image which is non executable jar containing `META-INF folder` only.
I want docker image to pick up `xxxxx-version.jar` which is executable containing `BOOT-INF` folder with all dependencies.

Please suggest me if I can make docker image to pick up some particular jar from repository.

Comment: So you know how to use Docker, you know how to use Gradle to build a jar, and you're getting *some* jar in your Docker image, correct?  So it's just a matter of configuring Gradle to pull in the correct .jar, correct?  Look here: https://container-solutions.com/how-to-build-docker-images-with-gradle/  or here http://thediscoblog.com/blog/2014/06/13/docker-containers-with-gradle-in-4-steps/

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks, I could find it helpful but still need to try various options available as i am still unable to get desired result.